# Firefox Addon manager blurry icons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I created an extension for Firefox and made a simple icon for it.
But when I tested it in the Addon manager the icon appeared blurry despite my source image was fine.

I started to experiment with different sizes and shapes of the icon.
Figured out that the icon container is 48x48 pixels and the default addon icon is 32x32.
But for any experiments the result was the same.

So I created a simple rectangle icon drawing it by pixels so it shouldn't blur anyway:

[image]

But the result blurred again:

[image]

There is some sub-pixels around the rectangle though the border should be crisp...
In pixels view:

[image]

Also I found the default extension icon (a puzzle piece) and in pixels it looks perfect but in the manager the borders are blurred a little though it's not obvious at first glance.

Comment: Very awesome investigation, and nice job sharing. Maybe we should file a bug of this on bugzilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was silly enough... The broblem was the page scale not 100% on the Addons page. Pressed `Ctrl+0` and all restored.

It happens sometimes on other web pages when I zoom in/out the view and images lose their sharpness.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is not happening when you save the image?  I don't know what app you are using, but many photo apps try to compress jpm images when you save them by default.  Check this first.

Usually this does not happen with `png` images, so you could try using a `png` image instead as well.